# How to include multiple php libraries in Symfony?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

so, I have some php files in my **apps/myprogram/lib**  folder. e.g. apps/myprogram/lib/myLibA.class.php

When I run in my modules/actions/ scripts, and try to use the functions in myLibA, I cannot.  because symfony complains that the myLibA class is not defined.

do I need to specify anywhere in the symfony framework that myLibA.class.php is a required library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symfony's autoloader looks by default for your classes in the top-level `<project>/lib` directory. Any file in that directory or below (with the exception of "vendor") will be searched for classes. Symfony searches for any .php file with class declarations and adds them to the autoload system.

Additionally, you can add search paths in your application's `autoload.yml` file. For example, for one of my applications I've put a third-party Flickr library in `<project>/vendor/phpFlickr`, and my `<project>/apps/frontend/config/autoload.yml` file looks like:

```
autoload:
    vendor_php_flickr:
        path: %SF_LIB_DIR%/vendor/phpFlickr
        recursive: on
```

That allows all classes below .../vendor/phpFlickr to be autoloaded.

Answer (score 0):

this is an alternative way, you can define/add to your preExecute this:

```
public function preExecute()
{
  $this->getContext()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Foo', 'Bar');
}
```

taken from (http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/92916/)