# How to load a class in symfony?

Tags: php, class, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I need to load a class in Symfony 1.4 but the simple placing of the file in */apps/frontend/lib* seems not to be enough.

```
class test
{ function foo ($foo) { echo $foo; }
}
```

and I tried to use it in an action:

```
  public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $a = new test();
    $a->foo('aaa');
  }
```

I have refreshed the cache and still:

`Fatal error: Class 'test' not found in ...`

Do I have to declare it somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to place your file in your project lib folder:

> myproject/lib

**[Updating]**
About loading a class from a file in `myproject/apps/frontend/lib/` maybe the problem is the filename where is the class.
I found in this page [A Gentle Introduction to symfony - Chapter 2 - Exploring Symfony's Code](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/02-Exploring-Symfony-s-Code) that:

> Symfony will then look for a MyClass definition in all files ending
>   with class.php in one of the project's lib/ directories. If the class
>   definition is found, it will be included automatically.
>
> So if you store all your classes in lib/ directories, you don't need
>   to include classes anymore. That's why symfony projects usually do not
>   contain any include_once or require_once statements.

Comment: Yup. See also my brief explanation of how the Symfony autoloader searches for classes in [this earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507440/how-to-include-multiple-php-libraries-in-symfony/5507557#5507557).

Comment: Thanks! the problem was at the name.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the other answer, classes in `/apps/frontend/lib/` *absolutely* should be loaded by the autoloader if you are in a `frontend` action.

Something else is going on here. Is your class actually named test? If you're in production, have you cleared your cache?

Comment: In my first answer I tried to provide a quick solution, and certainly not have been accurate. Thanks for making me think.